# Which is the conventional way of sending id - @PathParam or @HeaderParam or @QueryParam?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I am not asking for difference amongst all three. I am working on an application that is built using JAX-RS. It is using Hibernate to interact with the data store. Each user is associated with a particular account.

While I am deleting any user, I have to return the list of users existing for that account after the requested user is deleted. I don't need accountId to delete the user but I need it to get the list of users to return once the user is deleted. I am confused about which annotation would work as best practice?

```
//Sending accountId in path variable
@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/user/{accId}/{userId}")
public List<Users> deleteUser(@HeaderParam("token") String token, @PathParam("accId") Integer accId, @PathParam("userId") Integer userId) {
     userService.deleteUser(userId);
     return userService.getUsers(accId);
}

//Sending accountId in header
@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/user/{userId}")
public List<Users> deleteUser(@HeaderParam("token") String token, @HeaderParam("accId") Integer accId, @PathParam("userId") Integer userId) {
     userService.deleteUser(userId);
     return userService.getUsers(accId);
}

//Sending accountId as query string
@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/user/{userId}")
public List<Users> deleteUser(@HeaderParam("token") String token, @QueryParam("accId") Integer accId, @PathParam("userId") Integer userId) {
     userService.deleteUser(userId);
     return userService.getUsers(accId);
}
```

Comment: Can't you get the accountId through the userId? Surely they're related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is heavily opinion based and depends on the relationship between user and account.

If one user is connected to exactly one account I'd define the URLs like this:

```
@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/account/{accId}/user/{userId}")
public List<Users> deleteUser(@HeaderParam("token") String token, @PathParam("accId") 
        Integer accId, @PathParam("userId") Integer userId) {
    userService.deleteUser(userId);
    return userService.getUsers(accId);
}
```

If the same user might belong to different accounts, I'd split the requests into two, one for the DELETE and a second one to return the remaining users:

```
@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/user/{userId}")
public void deleteUser(@HeaderParam("token") String token, @PathParam("userId") Integer userId) {
    userService.deleteUser(userId);
}

@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/user")
public List<Users> getUsers(@HeaderParam("token") String token, @QueryParam("accId") Integer accId) {
    return userService.getUsers(accId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If URL is like `http://localhost:8080/app/index?param=value` use

> QueryParam

If URL is like `http://localhost:8080/app/index/value`

> PathParam

`HeaderParam` is usually used to get meta data or header data.

Comment: I have to create the URL. I am wondering which is the standard way out of 3?

Comment: It depends on URL type but QueryParam & PathParam are preferred

Comment: @DharitaChokshi There's no "standard" way, but header param would be weird. REST tends towards path parameters. All are valid-making this an opinion-based question. Use common sense: what matches your usage and API? What do you want to present to your consumers?

Comment: When you use PathParam you may have same URL with different data types. http://localhost:8080/app/index/int & http://localhost:8080/app/index/string it's prone to some unwanted errors if you map informally

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HttpServletRequest object in your request mapping in controller, and pass on the accID in headers of the request. And in the controller, get the value of the particular header using:

```
@DELETE
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/user/{userId}")
public List<Users> deleteUser(@HeaderParam("token") String token, @HeaderParam("accId") Integer accId, @PathParam("userId") Integer userId, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
     userService.deleteUser(userId);
     Integer accId = httpServletRequest.getHeader("accId");
     return userService.getUsers(accId);
}
```

There is no standard way out of the three scenarios mentioned by you. Its all dependent on the requirement and how you want to expose your apis and request parameters. And the choice is totally dependent on these parts only.